# larave nova Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Laravel Version: 6.9.0
Nova Version: 2.9.2
PHP Version: 7.3.10

after I update nova to latest version got out an **error**

```
/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Nova.php 224

on
return $resource::authorizedToViewAny($request)

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Class name must be a valid object or a string (View: /var/www/cportal/data/www/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/nova/resources/views/layout.blade.php)
 (View: /var/www/cportal/data/www/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/nova/resources/views/layout.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Class name must be a valid object or a string (View: /var/www/cportal/data/www/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/nova/resources/views/layout.blade.php) (0)
Class name must be a valid object or a string (0)

"Class name must be a valid object or a string (View: /var/www/cportal/data/www/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/nova/resources/views/layout.blade.php) (View: /var/ ▶"
```

```
    /**
     * Get the resources available for the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public static function availableResources(Request $request)
    {
        return collect(static::$resources)->filter(function ($resource) use ($request) {
            return $resource::authorizedToViewAny($request) &&
                $resource::availableForNavigation($request);
        })->all();
    }

    /**
     * Get the resources available for the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public static function globallySearchableResources(Request $request)
    {
        return collect(static::availableResources($request))
                    ->filter(function ($resource) {
                        return $resource::$globallySearchable;
```

Please help to fix this

Comment: Which is the line where you get the error at?

Comment: return $resource::authorizedToViewAny($request) &&

Answer (score 1):

After you have done a new Nova installation be sure to

```
composer update
```

and then run your usual housekeeping items:

```
php artisan nova:publish
php artisan config:cache
```

And that will fix this particular issue

Official docs here: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/installation.html#authorizing-nova

Comment: I spent 2 hours seacrhing online. `php artisan config:cache` fixd it. THANK YOU